# Unit testing WPF GUI Framework

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, user-interface, mocking, nunit

I am using NUnit to test my model, but what is the best framework to test the WPF GUI, That make it easy to test user input, binding ...

Thank you

Comment: see [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx)

Comment: There must be something recommended out there, this is a common problem I guess

Comment: Try http://white.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer to use MVVM.

This moves most of the code to the ViewModel. The ViewModel can be tested using the testing tools in Visual Studio such as MS Test or NUnit.

For UI tests that remain (mostly custom controls) you could use a UI Automation test suite such as [White on codeplex](http://white.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 2):

TestComplete is a great piece of software for automated UI testing - works with WPF.  http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing/

It will cost you though: at least $999.